# Custom iOS UI Element via HTML or Javascript?

Tags: javascript, ios, html, web

On an iPad, if you are on a web page, and select a block of text, a menu bar appears with a few options Copy | Select All | Define ...

Does anyone know how do add custom options to this menu, via HTML or javascript?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. To see what extensions Mobile Safari makes available to Web content, check out the Safari Web Content Guide on Apple's developer site.

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/Introduction/Introduction.html